# Moving information from one template to another in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

The question may be witty. But I am seriously looking if it is possible. I want to make data available in more than one template. This can be done easily by using Session object. But are there any alternatives apart from using Session? It could be anything like client side db or anything.

Suggestions gracefully accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head, there is:

- [session vars](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session)
- [reactive variables](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar)
- [client side collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)

Also, remember that at no point does meteor prevents you from using javascript globals. A lot of time it is the fastest way if you need something quick and simple and reactivity is either not required or not worth the hassle.

Comment: I too know these. But I am wondering if there are any other ways to do it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other meteor specific methods.